# Required textarea is being highlighted in red before submitting form

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Using React/Bootstrap to create a web app and have noticed a bug where when I open the form, the required textarea will be highlighted in red before I click submit.

Imgur album to show the problem (first picture is when the form is opened, second is after clicking submit) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/hswvH.jpg

I tried a couple different things, and the only one that worked was to remove the required tag (but this is obviously not acceptable).

Here is the code for the textarea:

```
  <textarea
    className="form-control"
    name="ticketNewDetailedInfo"
    rows="5"
    value={this.state.ticketNewDetailedInfo}
    onChange={this.handleInputChange}
    required 
  />
```

Obviously it should only be highlighted in red if it is empty when the user submits the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `required` attribute from the textarea and handle the form validation yourself. When the form is submitted check to make sure all the fields contain values. If it doesn't since you are using bootstrap you can give the field a class of `is-invalid` and it will turn the input field red as a visual queue for the user. Something quick and simple to get the idea would be:

```
validateFormValues( values ) {
   var passed = true;
   for( let i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) {
      if( values[i] === '' ) {
          passed = false;
      }
   }
   return passed;

}
```

Then in your textarea you could write

```
className={ `form-control ${ !this.state.passed ? 'is-invalid' : ''}` }
```

Comment: Thank you! I have it working correctly now. I'll have to finish writing the validation function. I also ended up doing this for the className:

```className={`form-control ${
                    !this.state.validForm &&
                    this.state.ticketNewDetailedInfo === ""
                      ? " is-invalid"
                      : ""
                  }`}```

This makes it outlined in red if the user submits with an invalid value, and then will remove the outline once they change the value. If they submit and it's still invalid, it's outlined red again.

Answer (score 0):

`this.handleInputChange` is what's checking that required field. You're calling this on the `onchange` event. This means as soon as you click into the textarea, it is checking those required fields.

Change your trigger event to something like `onsubmit` instead.